# Swift: wait for app execution till file downloads ends

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await

I have a problem, I can't solve by myself. But I think there has to be a very simple solution. So simple I can't see it :-(

I have a function that's downloads a file from a webserver and stores it on the device. this function works:

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: String, fileOnDevice: URL) async  {
  
    if let dataURL = URL(string: fileOnServer) {
        URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: dataURL) { (tempFileUrl, response, error) in
            
            if let dataTempFileUrl = tempFileUrl {
                do {
                    let urlData = try Data(contentsOf: dataTempFileUrl)

                    try urlData.write(to: fileOnDevice)
                    
              //      checkSavedFile(file: fileOnDevice)
                    
                    print("download successfull")
                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

I call this function in a simple SwiftUI view:

```
truct UpdateView: View {
    
    @State var text = "Loading"
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
        Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Hello, World!"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            Text(text)
        }
        .task()
        {
            print ("START downloadFile() ")
            await downloadFile(fileOnServer: htmlLinkForJSON, fileOnDevice: downloadedJSON)
           await downloadFile(fileOnServer: htmlLinkForCategories, fileOnDevice: downloadedCategories)
            print ("END downloadFile()")
            print ("---------")
            print ("Start checkSavedFile()")
            checkSavedFile(file: downloadedJSON)
            checkSavedFile(file: downloadedCategories)
            print ("END checkSavedFile()")
            print ("---------")
        }
    }      
}
```

Now my problem: As you can see on the console output the checkSavedFile() starts before the download ends. How can I pause my code till the downloads ends?
Do you know what I mean?

```
START downloadFile() 
END downloadFile()
---------
Start checkSavedFile()
checkSavedFile gestartet
file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB464055-A554-4B4B-9AB3-BF7FAD670A81/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C940BA4-99EB-4250-83CB-BA6D2AA9669B/Documents/downloadedJSON.txt available!
checkSavedFile gestartet
file:///Users/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/AB464055-A554-4B4B-9AB3-BF7FAD670A81/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C940BA4-99EB-4250-83CB-BA6D2AA9669B/Documents/downloadedCategories.txt available!
END checkSavedFile()
---------
2022-01-04 20:27:17.573376+0100 Blindzeln_Prototyp[4296:186653] [boringssl] boringssl_metrics_log_metric_block_invoke(151) Failed to log metrics
download successfull
download successfull
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to make `downloadFile` **really** `async` by using the appropriate async `URLSession` API. The completion handler API doesn't `wait`.

```
func downloadFile (fileOnServer: String, fileOnDevice: URL) async throws {
    guard let dataURL = URL(string: fileOnServer) else { throw URLError(.badURL) }
    let (dataTempFileUrl, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: dataURL)
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: dataTempFileUrl, to: fileOnDevice)
}
```

In the `task` you have add a `do - catch` block to handle the error(s)

```
.task()
    {
        do {
            print ("START downloadFile() ")
            try await downloadFile(fileOnServer: htmlLinkForJSON, fileOnDevice: downloadedJSON)
            try await downloadFile(fileOnServer: htmlLinkForCategories, fileOnDevice: downloadedCategories)
            print ("END downloadFile()")
            print ("---------")
            print ("Start checkSavedFile()")
            checkSavedFile(file: downloadedJSON)
            checkSavedFile(file: downloadedCategories)
            print ("END checkSavedFile()")
            print ("---------")
       } catch {
            print(error)
       }    
    }
```

Comment: Hi vadian! Thank you very much. Now it works like it should. Now I have a new todo on my bucket list: understanding exactly the differences between your and my code.  coding is learning :-)

Comment: For most of the common asynchronous APIs with completion handlers Apple added an `async` counterpart. In an `async` environment you must not use the completion handler API.

Comment: Loading the data to memory to write it again to disk is pointless. Note also that this might crash the app depending on the file size. Why not simply FileManager moveItem?

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks and of course. My focus was more on the async pattern.

Comment: I will have a look at FileManager moveItem. Thanks for the tipp